# Find and replace a part of a sring

Tags: c#, regex

I want to highlight the parts of a string with "*" on both ends using regex in c#

What I have tried:

```
replaced = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b123\b", "*123*");
replaced = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b234\b", "*234*");
replaced = Regex.Replace(text, @"\b335\b", "*335*");
```

Example:

highlight this: 123, 234, 335

input: `dsadf335aa`
output: `dsadf*335*aa`

My problem is that I have a list of strings to find and I don't know how to search for all of them.

Edit:

I have tried the suggestion of D Stanley, but there's a problem with it.
The second {s} is understood as a string...

[sintax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDqGG.png)

Comment: Do you mean for each string `s` replace `\bs\b` with `*s*`? How about `foreach(string s in list) { text = Regex.Replace(text, $@"\b{s}\b", "*{s}*");}`?

Comment: Also I don't think you need regex here - `text.Replace()` should be good enough.

Comment: `text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\d+", "*$0*");`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string s in list) 
{ 
    replaced = string.Format("*{0}*", s);
    newtexe = Regex.Replace(text, s, replaced);

    if (text != newtexe) 
       { break; } 
}
```

solved it :D thx for the help :))